# Distinction in finite case vs infinite case measure theorems

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about the logic that comes up in a handful of theorems in basic measure theory. For example, given a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is of measure zero if it can be covered by a countable collection of (open) intervals whose sum of all lengths is less than any given positive number. Then the union of a countable collection of sets with measure zero is also of measure zero.

(Question below proof)

Proof: Let $\{A_n\}$ be a countable collection of sets with measure zero (meaning it is either a finite or countably infinite collection of sets). Then for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a countable collection of open intervals $\{I_{n,k}\}$ (with end points $a_k$ and $b_k$ and length/measure $m(I_{n,k})=b_k-a_k$) that covers $A_n$, i.e.
$$A_n\subset \bigcup_k I_{n,k}$$
and such that
$$\sum_k (b_k-a_k) <\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.$$
So, we see that,
$$\bigcup_n A_n \subset \bigcup_n \bigcup_k I_{n,k}$$
and
$$\sum_n\sum_k m(I_{n,k}) < \sum_n \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}=\epsilon$$

My question is how does this proof justify the differences between a finite collection and a countably infinite collection? The use of the sum of a geometric series seems unjustified unless we are truly summing from $1$ to $\infty$. Perhaps it assumes the finite case is obvious to the reader?

For, if we had $A_1,\dotso, A_n$, then for each $1\leq j\leq n$ we have there exists some countable collection $\{I_{j,k}\}$ that covers $A_j$ and has sums of lengths less than $\frac{\epsilon}{n}$, i.e.
$$\sum_k m(I_{j,k}) < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$$ and since
$$\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n \bigcup_k I_{j,k}$$
we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_k b_k-a_k < \epsilon$$

Also, does it not matter that we aren't considering whether the collection that covers $A_n$ (or $A_j$ in the finite case) is finite or countably infinite?

Thanks in advanced and sorry if this is a messy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collection $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ is finite, one can just extend it to a countable collection by padding it with $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n>k$. This doesn't change the union of the collection. A similar idea goes for the covering collection, that is, one can always assume without loss of generality it is countably infinite purely for notational convenience.

Comment: Thank you, this clears things up. Is there any similar remark for the sums?

Comment: It is certainly true that a finite sum can be regarded as an infinite one by padding it with zeros too.

Comment: Well yes, but it seems (to me) if do that, you cant use the geometric sum and must use the other argument for the finite case. No?

Comment: Hm. At this point I may not be properly understanding, but with the inequality sign it does not seem to matter: $0<\epsilon/2^n$.

Comment: ah yes i now understand hahah wow that was dumb of me. Thank you a lot